# MSVC Inline Assembly: Freeing FPU registers for performance

Tags: c, performance, visual-c++, inline-assembly, fpu

While playing a little with FPU using MSVC's Inline Assembly, I got a little confused about freeing FPU registers in favor of increasing performance...

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double fpu_add(register double x, register double y) {
    double res = 0.0;

    __asm {
        fld x
        fld y
        fadd
        fstp res
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    double x = fpu_add(5.0, 2.0);
    (void) printf("x = %f\n", x);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When do I have to `ffree` the FPU registers in Inline Assembly?

In that example would performance be better if I decided to `ffree` the `st(1)` register?

Also is `fstp` a shorthand for instructions below?

```c
__asm {
    fst res
    ffree st(0)
}
```

> NOTE: I know FPU instructions are a bit old nowdays, But dealing with them as another option along with SSE

Comment: FWIW, these are legacy floating point instructions that don't get used much anymore.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I know...

Comment: You say this is for 'performance' but pretty much anything you do with inline asm is going to be slower than letting the compiler optimize things.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I see... But does this mean I can't write something faster than what the compiler would generate/optimize in cases like this one?

If yes, Then shall I keep portability and performance all time to the compiler?

Comment: certainly for a simple add like this, you won't beat what the compiler does.  For complex code on an older CPU, where the compiler is likely optimizing for something newer, you might do better, but that is largely because newer compilers don't really support older cpus.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yep, But taking this small snippet to ask about freeing registers and of course compilers would do better most times even with SSE, Anyway thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ffree` instruction allows you to mark any slot of the x87 fo stack as `free` without actually changing the stack pointer.  So `ffree st(0)` does *NOT* pop the stack, just marks the top value of the stack as free/invalid, so any following instruction that tries to access it will get a floating point exception.

To actually pop to the stack you need both `ffree st(0)` and `fincstp` (to increment the pointer).  Or better, `fstp st(0)` to do both those things with a single cheap instruction.  Or `fstp st(1)` to keep the top-of-stack value and discard the old `st(1)`.

But it's usually even better and easier (and faster) to use the `p` suffixed versions of other instructions.  In your case, you probably want

```
__asm {
    fld x     // push x on the stack
    fld y     // push y on the stack
    faddp     // pop a value and add it to the (now) tos
    fstp res  // pop and store tos
}
```

This ends up pushing and popping two values, leaving the fp stack in the same state as it was before.  Leaving stuff on the fp stack is likely to cause problems with other fp code, if the compiler is generating x87 fp code, so should be avoided.

Or even better, use memory-source `fadd` to save instructions, if you're optimizing for CPUs where that's not slower.  (Check [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) microarch PDF and instruction tables for P5 Pentium and newer: seems to be fine, at least break even, and saves a uop on more modern CPUs like Core2 that can do micro-fusion of memory source operands.)

```
    __asm {
        fld x     // push x on the stack
        fadd y    // ST0 += y
        fstp res  // pop and store tos
    }
```

But MSVC inline asm is inherently slow for wrapping a single instruction like `fadd`, forcing inputs to be in memory, even if the compiler had them available in registers before the asm statement.  And forcing the result to be stored in the asm and then reloaded for the `return` statement, unless you use a hack like leaving a value in `st(0)` and falling off the end of a function without a `return` statement.  (MSVC does actually support this even when inlining, but clang-cl / clang `-fasm-blocks` does not.)

GNU C inline asm could wrap a single `fadd` instruction with appropriate constraints to ask for inputs in x87 registers and tell the compiler where the output is (in `st(0)`), but you'd still have to choose between `fadd` and `faddp`, not letting the compiler pick based on whether it had values in registers or a value from memory.  (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info)

Compilers aren't terrible, they will make code at least this good from plain C source.  Inline asm is generally not useful for performance, unless you're writing a whole loop that's carefully tuned for a specific CPU, or for a case where the compiler does a poor job with something.  (Look at the compiler's optimized asm output, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: If you *do* need to just pop the FP stack, `fstp st(0)` is the way to do it, combining ffree and fincstp.  (@Rabios).  This can sometimes happen for longer calculations, where you have multiple temporaries that are needed and can't all be popped by the computation instructions you want to use.

Comment: Here, `fld x` / `fadd y` / `fstp res` is even shorter.  But still won't be better than what the compiler does on its own, since MSVC inline asm syntax inherently sucks, forcing inputs to be in memory, and the `return res` forces a reload into st0 instead of just leaving the value there after `fadd`.  Especially not if you're doing a normal build that can let the compiler use SSE2 instructions.

Comment: (I expanded your answer more than I'd planned when I started editing.  You might want to have a look and make sure you like what I wrote.)  See also http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap4.htm for `fstp st(0)` being a thing.